# apds 9960 on raspberry pi zero

Tags: pi-zero, device-tree

I would like to use the `apds9960` (light/gesture sensor) on rp0 - **utilizing the kernel iio driver**, which is already available, but there is no dt overlay yet. I guess I need to:

- write the `dts` file
- compile it to `dtb`
- add to overlays
- specify dtoverlay in `config.txt`
- find the device in `/sys/bus/iio/devices`

Is someone able to do/help with the first point or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. There are current findings:

- The DTS might look like this (`i2c-apds9960.dts`):

  ```
  /dts-v1/;
  /plugin/;

  / {
      compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

      fragment@0 {
          target = <&i2c_arm>;
          __overlay__ {
              #address-cells = <1>;
              #size-cells = <0>;
              status = "okay";

              apds9960: apds9960@39 {
                  compatible = "avago,apds9960";
                  reg = <0x39>;
                  interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                  interrupts = <4 2>;
                  #gpio-cells = <2>;
              };
          };
      };

      __overrides__ {
          int_pin = <&apds9960>,"interrupts:0";
          addr = <&apds9960>,"reg:0";
      };
  };
  ```
- Compilation to DTB (one of possible methods):

  ```
  git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dtc/dtc.git
  cd dtc
  make
  ./dtc i2c-apds9960.dts > i2c-apds9960.dtbo
  cp i2c-apds9960.dts /mnt/pi-zero/boot/overlays
  ```
- Update of the `config.txt`:

  ```
  dtoverlay=i2c-apds9960
  dtparam=int_pin=4 # For the case the pin needs to be different than in DTC
  ```
- Locate the device:

  ```
  # cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device0/name
  apds9960
  ```